# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate') - Drawer Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm receiving - undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate'). I know there are already some answers about this issue but I didn't find any for Drawer Navigator, all I found were for Stack Navigator. (I'm using react-navigation V3)
So here is my DrawerNavigator.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, Dimensions, Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer, StackNavigator, withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
import {Header} from 'react-native-elements';
import Hamburger from 'react-native-animated-hamburger';

class MenuButton1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        active: false,
      }

  }
  render () {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
      return (
          <React.Fragment>   
          <Hamburger active={this.state.active}
     type="cross"
     onPress={() => this.setState({active: !this.state.active}) || navigate('DrawerOpen')} 
     />   
          </React.Fragment>
      )
  }
}


class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Header
          leftComponent={<MenuButton1 />}
          />

        <View style={{top: 30 }}>
            <Text> Hello </Text>
        </View>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  }



const WIDTF = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const DrawerConfig = {
    drawerWidth: WIDTF*0.80,
    draertType: 'slide'    
}

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator ({
    HomeScreen: {
      screen: HomeScreen,

    }
},
  DrawerConfig
);


export default createAppContainer (DrawerNavigator);
```

And my App.js :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DrawerNavigator from './components/DrawerNavigator';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <DrawerNavigator />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

And the issue :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywy5D.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**navigation object is only available on screens that are direct children of your drawer navigator**

You could wrap your `MenuButton1` with `withNavigation` to get access to the navigation object ... or simply wrap your navigation logic in a method and pass it as a prop to your `MenuButton` like:

```
class MenuButton1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // ...
  }

  render() {
    const { onDrawerOpen } = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Hamburger
          active={this.state.active}
          type="cross"
          onPress={() => this.setState({ active: !this.state.active }) || onDrawerOpen()
          }
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

-

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header
          leftComponent={(
            <MenuButton1
              onDrawerOpen={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}
            />
)}
        />

        <View style={{ top: 30 }}>
          <Text> Hello </Text>
        </View>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It says - _this3.props.navigate is not a function.(In '_this3.props.navigate('DrawerOpen'), '_this3.props.navigate' is undefined)

Comment: I'm sorry ... I forgot `navigation` ... correct ref to navigate fn is: `this.props.navigation.navigate`

Comment: Now I can see only the animation of the Hamburger Icon, but it doesn't open the drawer. :D I'm trying to figure it about 3 weeks already. :D

Comment: Alright :) ... have you tried `this.props.navigation.openDrawer();` instead ?